# 12V motor or 24V motor for go-cart?

Tags: voltage

I am making a PVC electric go-cart. I want to know which is better: a 12V motor or a 24V motor?

I want good speed and good torque, because I don't want it to struggle with my weight (I weigh around 210 lb). So what's better for this project?

Comment: From your text I’m not quite sure what you want to accomplish. 12V and 24V are not the correct design parameter for speed and torque spec. You can accomplish equal performance with both.

Comment: Take both, one for left wheels, one for right ones. See which side goes better

Comment: @GregoryKornblum This calles for the Myth Busters!

Comment: Then  what do I Need to look Up for, when searching for torque, gears, RPM, wats or amps?

Comment: @MaicolRivera Check out rudys answer

Comment: A series wound dc motor will produce higher torque than a parallel wound dc motor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The voltage of the motor does not determine the torque. A motor manufacture can produce a motor that operates on 12 volts, another one on 24 volts, and the mechanical output can be the same.

But if I were to have the option of selecting between two identical motors, one being 12 volts and the other 24 volts, I would pic the 24 volt motor. For the same power the current will be half. This will allow for thinner wire to be used and control electronics that will not have to switch as high a current. Or the same size of wire can be used and there would be less power loss in the wiring if 24 volts was used.

But another consideration is the available battery. Getting a single 12 volt battery is easy and relatively less expensive. For 24 volt there would be either two 12 volt batteries in series. It adds some complexity but that might be acceptable. Or for example, if a lithium battery pack were available in 24 volts (approximately) with the required capacity, then that might be a good solution.

Basically there are a lot of considerations and tradeoffs that can be made. The whole design needs to be considered. All the pieces. And as I said, the actual motor voltage is not relevant as far as output power delivered. Look at what someone else has done and see if it makes sense, if you can find the equivalent components you need.

Comment: Thank you Rudy, this has helped me a lot. But What do I need to look for when I'm searching for more torque? Is it the gears, RPM, wats or Amps?

Comment: Yes that is a good question and difficult to answer. That is why I suggest looking at what other people have done. Will the motor be direct drive to the wheels or will there be gears, a transmission, cogged belt? The gearing will have an impact of the torgue you will need. So you need to know the whole drivetrain. The diameter of the wheels. Find similar examples then work back from there.

Comment: Google "electric go cart"   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDW6k__ms6M&vl=en  and more.

Comment: In a toy you need to keep voltage low to save on batteries.

Comment: "In a toy you need to keep voltage low to save on batteries." It is not a "toy". And keeping voltage low has nothing to do with saving batteries. Battery power will be consumed depending on how much load there is and the expectations of the user. Drive it hard and with lots of acceleration and it will consume more power, but will be more fun. And with a go-cart, fun is the primary goal.

Comment: Thanks Rudy, Im stiking to 24V, all thoe  looking foward to use a 24V 3HP electric motor.

Comment: I'm sure you are going to have a lot of fun with this project. Good luck.

Comment: @Rudy to save battery- doesn't mean to keep it smaller. It means to keep it's voltage lower, because it's way better for batteries. Otherwise you have to stack them in series, which impacts reliability and maximum working voltage greatly. So generally it's better to work with lower voltage and to invest in wires a little bit. This is one of the reasons why small drones use very low voltage motors.

Comment: @Gregory I see what you are saying. While drones may use lower voltage, when the power gets higher the current demands are quite high. Auto batteries are 12 volts mainly due to historical reasons, but for electric cars the voltage used is higher. The Chevy Volt battery is 300 volts. I designed a motor controller for a 3/4hp 12v motor, 55 amps at full load, current limited to 140 amps at start up so it wouldn't overload the battery. This was for sand spreaders.  https://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/product_200578310_200578310  The design would have been easier if I could have used 24 volts.

Comment: I tried to fit what I had to say in the character limit, I should have just decided to do two posts. A 12 volt battery is made up of six cells in series. And there are no concerns about imbalanced charging. And for lithium ion batteries there are special charge controllers that do control cell imbalances.  http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt322/slyt322.pdf

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tp6hB1eFMUs  and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1e_gj4dASl0

Comment: Ok guys, you seem that you know lot of this topic, is there a way I can put two motors one with lots of torque and one with lots of speed. The one with torque to start mooving and altern the motors to the one with speed once it all ready mooving. How can I change from one motor to a nother? Can I do it with arduino?

Comment: In fact there is such way. You need a custom motor with two sets of winfings, then you can operate them in parallel for speed and in series for torque. But i think this is not very efficient, only if you have some constraints that prevent using a normal motor.